# Adding a Huge Dataset into Oracle Database

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, dataset

I have a huge data set of two number sets ~ Millions that need to be processed at one time in a batch.

Is using an ArrayList of objects the best way to store these objects into memory then into a database

```
List<Object> objects = new ArrayList<Object>()
objects.add(new Object("101", "101"))
```

I then read these items one by one into a database using Spring's jdbcTemplate.

```
for(Object object: objects) 
jdbcTemplate.update("INSERT INTO TABLEOFNUMBERS(ITEM1, ITEM2) values(?, ?)", object.get1(), object.get2();
```

Is there any way that I can get this added into the database at a quicker rate?

Comment: May I assume you read the data in from a file or any other stream ? Then it might be more appropriate to directly read them in a loop and inset them via a **prepared SQL** statement. Depending on how well the RDBMS supports prepared statements it should boost the whole thing significantly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I ended up doing it using Spring's JDBC Template.

```
jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate("INSERT INTO TABLEOFNUMBERS(ITEM1, ITEM2) values (:1, :2)",
                new BatchPreparedStatementSetter() {
            public void setValues(PreparedStatement ps, int i ) throws SQLException {
                ps.setString(1, batch.get(i).getITEM1());
                ps.setString(2, batch.get(i).getITEM2());
            }

            public int getBatchSize() {
                return batch.size();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

If the data source is a file, it might be better to bypass your OO language/tool altogether and use Oracle's utility SQL Loader instead.
If you must make individual SQL INSERT statements, and the Oracle version is 11gR2 or better, try the APPEND_VALUES hint, as in: 
    INSERT /*+ APPEND_VALUES */ INTO TABLEOFNUMBERS...
That does a direct path insert, more efficient than conventional path because it bypasses the buffer cache in Oracle's SGA memory and instead writes blocks directly to the datafiles.
Here's another article on APPEND_VALUES:
http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/11g/append-values-hint-11gr2.php

Answer (score 1):

The INSERT cost might be hard to get around when using jdbc (as opposed to some oracle bulk loader), but you can try to save significant time by cutting on the millions network round trips. You can try to create one PLSQL block or stored procedure that loads 20 at a time (20 inserts each block with it's own bind variable to avoid reparsing).

The APPEND_VALUES might help too on the time it takes to insert, but it doesn't reuse space available on the table due to deletes. This might cause excessive table growth.